# How to apply a rotation matrix R(3*3) and vector translation T(3*1) to an image in matlab?

Tags: matlab, image-rotation, image-translation

I have two images `I1` and `I2`, and I get the rotation matrix `R (3*3)` and the translation vector `T (3*1)` between this two images. Now I want to apply this `R` and `T` in `I1` to get the aligned image `J` from `I1`. I try this code but didn't work :

```
J=(I1.*R)+T;
```

some help please

Answer (score 0):

You should remove the dot, and do it like that:

```
J=(R*I1)+T;
```

The operation .* is an entry-wise product, while you need the usual matrix multiplication.

Comment: I always have the same error message even with `(R * I1) + T`, `I1` is of size `N * M * 3` is this the problem ??

Comment: In such case, the dimensions just do not match. You cannot apply a 3-by-3 rotation matrix on an N-by-M-by-3 image.